# Need to set color of <h1> link

Tags: html, css

This is the css for setting the color for h1 text that is linked:

```css
.nav-left h1 a,
a:visited {
  color: #055830;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-left">
  <h1><a href="/index.php/housing/">Housing</a></h1>
</div>
```

It does not look like it is working appropriately, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about:

```
.nav-left h1 a:visited{
    color:#055830;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

if you want the colour to be the same for unvisited links you'll need to add a specific selector for that as well

```
.nav-left h1 a:link, .nav-left h1 a:visited {
    color:#055830;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer. It seems to better answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

If you want them the same, you must be specific:

.nav-left h1 a, a:visited

is not the same as:

.nav-left h1 a, **.nav-left h1 a**:visited

Answer (score 2):

```
.nav-left h1 a {
    color: #055830;
}
```

You don't need to add a:visited if it is the same color.